# How can I redirect users to different directories based on session data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, function, authentication

I have a PHP/MySQL based website with folders for member pages and folders for admin pages. I want to direct the users to the different pages according to how they login - as a member or as a admin (from the main user pages) - this is the function I've tried and it doesn't work.

How can I write a function that will work for this?

```
function connectadmin($level) {
    if ($level === "Administrator"){
        include('admin/home.php');
    }elseif ($level === "Member"){
        include('member/home.php');
    }
}

connectadmin($level);
```

Comment: use header('Location:desiredpage');
include will not redirect to any page it will include the code of that file..

Comment: @habibulhaq, thank you. I tried this and it still isn't working. Any help will be appreciated, though. God bless you for trying to help me. I'm a newbie to all of this so it is really helpful for you to provide any input.

Comment: how did you get this value of $level?? plus try the if check with double equal to sign.. because it seems there is no need to check the value type..

Comment: @habib ul haq: Dangersous advice - in the absence of any other control mechanism, admin functionality is exposed to all.

Comment: @Regina Shepherd Riddle: "It doesn't work" is not  a meaningful analysis.

Comment: @habibulhaq  - It is almost there - it is working, although I had to put the if inside another function - a connection function - to get it to work, but now, once I'm to the admin home.php it will not show my login as it would on the regular user pages and the links on the logged in admin pages folder keep going back to home even though they are supposed to go to different pages. Any advice is appreciated. God bless you all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should redirect your users, not include files:

```
 // At beggining of this file insert this line
 // Start session
 session_start();

function connectadmin($level) {
    if ($level === "Administrator"){

        // Set user role
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'Administrator';

        // Redirect user
        header('Location: admin/home.php');
        exit();
    }elseif ($level === "Member"){

        // Set user role
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'Member';

        // Redirect user
        header('Location: member/home.php');
        exit();
    }
}

// $level should be something you retrieve from your Database for example
// And perhaps, should be 'Administrator' or 'Member' following your example
connectadmin($level);
```

And after redirect user don't forget to validate if the logged in user have access to the redirected page.

Edit: For example, if you want to validate if user is Administrator and have access to the page admin/home.php, do something like this:

```
// You should get from your database, some file or use sessions, 
// in your function I have used sessions, so lets use them here too

// At beggining of your file use this
session_start();

// If user is not Administrator
if($_SESSION['role'] !== 'Administrator'){

    // It's not admin, let redirect him to somewhere else or show him a Access not allowed page
    header('Location: accessNotAllowed.php');
    exit();

}
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried this and it still doesn't work, but I am very grateful for your time. God bless you for trying to help me!!!

Comment: @Imarcelocc - How do I validate if the logged in user has access to the redirected page exactly? I'm sorry if I sound dumb - I'm just learning. Thanks for any help and God bless you.

Comment: Your welcome, but this code should work for you, I have try it and its working, maybe something else with your code :)

Comment: @Imarcelocc - Is there a need to have `session_start()` inside each of the if statements? I'm pretty sure that if you placed at the very beginning of the file, it will still register. Will this cause "Headers already been sent"?

Comment: @Phorce best pratice is to placed on top and once, I have changed to avoid confusion, thanks. But in this case will not trigger "Headers already been sent"  because `session_start()` - Start new or resume existing session

Comment: Now it will go to the admin page when I login from a user page, but it will only stay on home.php - the links to the other pages beneath the admin folder are always going to home.php??? Any idea what would cause this? Thank you.

Comment: @ReginaShepherdRiddle what I understand for your question is that you have only one form to login, if user is Administrator it should be redirected to `admin/home.php` and if user is a Member he should be redirected to `member/home.php`.
You should see when a user login if its Administrator or Member, then you should pass that value to your function in the `$level` variable to `connectadmin($level);`.
If you have some diferent question please ask another question and show us some example from your code or some info that could help us help you.

Comment: @Imarcelocc Actually I have a login form at the top of every page - only when a member or admin is logged in it shows Welcome, Administrator, Angie - for example and it shows this on every page of the main pages - lower pages intended for a regular user. When it redirects to the the Admin pages, however, nothing shows in the login portion and it won't move from the home.php when I click on different links - for example a link is to invoices.php and I click it and it stays on home.php. Any ideas will help? Your ideas are valuable - please make a suggestion for what I should do about posting.

Comment: @ReginaShepherdRiddle, if you have sure that other links are correctly set (try to pass mouse hover and at left bottom of your browser you should see where it should go when you click it) maybe its some javascript problem.
Open your console and check if there are some errors.
If your website is on live maybe you can share it.

Comment: @Imarclocc, at the moment, I'm developing in xampp. But, yes - hovering over the link shows the correct link in the lower left of the browser so I'm sure I have my links right. If clicked though, they move straight back to home. And I'm totally uncertain as to why my user information isn't showing up in the login section. it's empty with only a logout button, which I might add, doesn't work - everything (nearly everything) works from the root directory - it's just when I'm in the admin or member directories that things go haywire.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without code is difficult to debug...try to make another question with the relevant information.